# UI of input file type

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser

HI

i am using

```
<input type="file">
```

it has different UI on IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari
i want something that can generate same UI on all 4 browser.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not possible to directly change the appearance, the only way is using complicated client side script - jQuery is doing all the work for you, see Erik answer..

Comment: @Shadow - cant it be done using css/ javascript? i cant use jquery

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript. it's possible with CSS as well but more complicated. This one looks fine, think I even used it in the past: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: actually jquery changes the UI completely and i dont want that ... i went through this link before as well. but the input box over there will not show the name(preferably the complete file path) of the chosen file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this did the work for me :)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<title>New Page 1</title>
<style type="text/css">
div.fileinputs {
    position: relative;
}

img.fakefile, input.fakefile {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
z-index: 1;
}

input.file {
position: relative;
text-align: right;
-moz-opacity:0 ;
filter:alpha(opacity: 0);
opacity: 0;
z-index: 2;
}</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
function HandleFileButtonClick() 
  {    
    document.getElementById("xyz").value =document.getElementById("abc").value; 
    }  


</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="fileinputs">
    <input type="file" id="abc" class="file"  onchange="HandleFileButtonClick();" />
        <input type="text" id="xyz" class="fakefile" />
        <img src="browse button.bmp" class="fakefile" style="position: absolute; left: 150; top: 0" width="61" height="22"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://pixelmatrixdesign.com/uniform/

Uniform will allow you to easily skin the input element for uploads.

Comment: @Eric - it has to be using css or javascript and normal html. i cannot use jquery and other things...

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers (at least recent versions of Firefox) don't allow you to type a filename any more, as a security precaution. You can only select a file graphically. I believe Chrome is the same way.

What sort of UI are you talking about? If you mean another way to select a file... I don't think there's another way (also a security precaution).

Comment: i mean the input tag and button should be displayed on all browsers.. can it be done using javascript or any other thing ?